# JPA Eclipselink query parse problem in windows 7

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, eclipselink

I have a standalone spring boot web service which uses eclipselink v2.7.3. I have query in NamedQuery inside my class.

```
 SELECT m , o.iduserinsert.id as iduserinsert FROM Mytable
 m, Order1 o  WHERE o.idmytable=m and (o.id is null or o.idorderstatus.id 
in (1,3,4))  and m.iddepartment = :iddepartment and m.isactive = :isActive 
 and m.idtablestatus.id < 5 and (m.idparent is null or m.idparent < 0) 
order by m.id desc
```

In windows server 2008, windows10 this web service runs fine. However when i run it on windows7, it crashes and shutdowns because of below error:

> The SQL query contains a malformed ending

How this same piece of code works on one system and not on other?

**[UPDATE]**

The reason for that was interface language of windows OS. It was Turkish. JPA parser malfunctions in Turkish language. I installed English lang pack, avoided the issue. But I still can't find real solution without changing interface language of OS

Comment: what is the link between m and o? is o.idmytable the foreign key towards m.id? Is this mapping specified in the entities?

Comment: yes. o.idmytable is Mytable entity. Order1 and MyTable is mapped by joincolumn and o.idmytable=m works like o.idmytable.id=m.id, no difference

Comment: try this as a named query to see if it changes the result:
SELECT m , o.iduserinsert.id as iduserinsert FROM Order1 o JOIN o.idmytable m  WHERE (o.id is null or o.idorderstatus.id 
in (1,3,4))  and m.iddepartment = :iddepartment and m.isactive = :isActive 
 and m.idtablestatus.id < 5 and (m.idparent is null or m.idparent < 0) 
order by m.id desc

Comment: Thanks @mahieus, the reason for that was language of windows OS. JPA parser malfunctions in Turkish language. I installed English lang pack, solved issue

Comment: No problem glad I could help. If you can't find the issue always try to get more information out of the system.

Answer (score 1):

try this as a named query to see if it changes the result:

```
SELECT m , o.iduserinsert.id as iduserinsert FROM Order1 o JOIN o.idmytable m WHERE (o.id is null or o.idorderstatus.id in (1,3,4)) and m.iddepartment = :iddepartment and m.isactive = :isActive and m.idtablestatus.id < 5 and (m.idparent is null or m.idparent < 0) order by m.id desc
```

This will probably give you a clearer view of what happened.